# Consumer poll kafka streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming

https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#poll(long)

I would like to use the poll based interface (above) to pick messages from kafka streaming (see link below). How can i set the timeout property when i use the direct stream approach from Spark.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Any advice on handling this type of interaction is welcome :) thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: No, I did not... I stopped digging into this after a while.